# Python scraping from website. selecting TR elements based on multiple class attrs

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I am scraping from the following page: https://kenpom.com/index.php?y=2018

The page shows a list of every Divison 1 college basketball team. Each row is for one team. I want to assign every team-row to a variable called "teams". The problem is that after each 40 teams there are two header rows that I do not want to include. These rows are unique as they have a class of "thead1" and "thead2". The rows that I want to grab have a class of None or "bold-bottom". So essentially i need to iterate through every tr element in that table and grab any that has a class of None or "bold-bottom". My attempt below does not work. It returns a count of 35 when it should be 353

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url ='https://kenpom.com/index.php?y=2018'
r = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(r, 'lxml')

table = soup.find('table',{'id':'ratings-table'}).tbody
teams = table.findAll('tr',attrs = {'class':(None or 'bold-bottom')})
print(len(teams))
```

Comment: If its a dynamically updated and created site by JavaScript, you will need to use selenium

Comment: I don't believe that it is. Basically I need to know how to find tr elements in that table that have a class of None or "bold-bottom". LIne 9 in my code sample.